# Galaxy S3 - user agent detection

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, user-agent

The following script works for the most part in detecting Android devices:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
//do stuff

}
```

However, on the Galaxy S3, isAndroid is false. How can I account for this device?

Comment: Why not just console.log the string to see what it produces?

Comment: My S3 announces itself to be `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; GT-I9300` ... on the stock browser, so that should work.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy because I don't know how to check the console on a phone.

Comment: Maybe this particular device was using a fake user agent. The S3 allows you to change that right?

Comment: why checking if it's an Android device using an Android application under Android ?

Comment: You should be able to display the UA string using an alert() dialog (or printing it to the page somewhere). Also, user-agent detection isn't always the best way to handle incompatibilities between browsers, if that's what you're trying to do (there might be a less messy solution).

Comment: @axis it's a website that could be viewed on an Android device, but also any other kind of device. If it's Android, I want to change some text and buttons.